# Understanding passwd --keep-tokens

Tags: linux, password, options

On GNU/Linux, I do have trouble understanding the meaning of the `--keep-tokens` option for `passwd`. As it doesn't seem to be much used as I am not able to find any examples and only online copies of `man` pages… so any example of practical use would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, from what it's describing in the man page (here from my Fedora 20's version of the `passwd` man page):

*excerpt*

```
-k, --keep
          The option -k is used to indicate that the update should only be
          for expired authentication tokens (passwords); the user wishes to
          keep  their non-expired tokens as before.
```

It's basically stating that with this switch included, if your password (token) hasn't expired as of yet, then it will continue to keep the one that's already on file for you, even if you've requested that it be changed. If on the other-hand your password has expired, then it will change it, as you've requested.

However when I tested it, it did not appear to work for me. I did find this forum post that described this exact interpretation as well and it was not working for them either.

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=50649

Comment: About the same thing here: As long as there is an active password set only `root` can change it (as expected). As user to whom the password belongs there I don't see any difference when trying to set a new password with/without the '--keep-tokens` option. Doesn't work.